# How to iteratively print output images in R

Tags: r, image, output, iteration

I have a large bunch of input files for which I want to run the same function on and get an output image for each file with the same file names. I am writing an R script to run on the command line.

This is what I have so far... It creates a file called "$image" for only one of my input files and that's it. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
library(seqLogo)

files <- list.files(path="/path/to/all/files", pattern="*.pwm", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

for (i in files){
    motif <- read.table(i, header=F, sep="\t")
    pwmot <- makePWM(motif)
    png("$image.png", width=1000)
    seqLogo(pwmot)
    dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Well, you are looping over all the files, but the file name never changes. So you end up over-writing the image from the previous loop.

Comment: Use something like `png(paste(i,".png",sep=""),width=1000)`.

Comment: Thank you both! I was sat here thinking there was some other issue! It has worked thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
png("image%03d.png", width=1000)
for (i in files){
    motif <- read.table(i, header=F, sep="\t")
    pwmot <- makePWM(motif)    
    seqLogo(pwmot)
}
dev.off()
```

R will sequentially label the images "image001.png", "image002.png", etc. The numbering will stop when you call `dev.off()` and starts over again at the next `png()` call. You can change the format using a formatting string like those documented in `?sprintf`